# MPAndroidChart: legend entries on the same high as the corresponding lines

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to make a linechart using MPAndroidChart with multiple datasets. The thing is I want the legend to be on the left to the chart and each entry in the legend should be on the same height as the corresponding line like in the picture below.

[LineChart screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9uBg.png)

I want the legend entries to be positioned like the orange circles on the left. So far I've tried to use setYEntrySpace() on the legend object but everything goes off when zooming or scaling the chart. Is there a method that can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can disable zooming of the chart

Comment: But I need zooming to be enabled.